# Is 'give a speech' idiomatic English?

Tags: idioms, expressions

Is 'give a speech' idiomatic in English?

An instance I can think of would be “When that happened, my teacher *gave a speech*, and then said, "Now everybody wish Elbe a merry Christmas!"'

As a bonus question, can anyone suggest an alternative expression which renders the same emphasis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although verbs have often been called 'doing words' when the part of speech has been introduced to young children, this is a crude, partial, definition which can cause problems later on.

One set of verbs that need special explanation are *link verbs*, which show a property of (or redefine) the referent of a sentence's subject (though some may also indicate a transformation – from or to the said state, say):

> Mr Cameron is the Prime Minister.
>
> John is a vet.
>
> Jill grew tired.

(Imagine a young child naively saying 'Mr Cameron - Prime Minister.' or 'John - vet.' to see the linking function that adult grammar demands.)

Another set is [*delexical verbs*](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/delexical-verbs-have-take-make-and-give), where the verb *is* usually used to describe an action, but is really bleached of any particular meaning:

> John had / took a bath.
>
> Sally made a good suggestion.
>
> My teacher gave / delivered a surprisingly interesting speech.

I'm including this rather long intro because one needs to consider what the terms 'idiomatic' and 'idiom' usually mean (and there is a large difference between the usual senses) before one can sensibly respond to OP's question.

To summarise:

(1) 'Give a speech' is a very common expression – it is 'idiomatic English.'

(2) 'Give' is not used in its primary (donate, cede etc) sense here; this is a delexical usage.

(3) We wouldn't say 'give a story' or 'give a tale', but we *would* say 'give a sermon' or 'give a lecture' – so the usage is rather idiosyncratic. This probably qualifies the expression as an 'idiom' in the usual sense.

Comment: +1, but how does the answer answer to the question I posed?

Comment: Well, "delivered a speech" is an alternative. As to whether or not "to give a speech" is idiomatic, that depends on how other languages/cultures phrase the same thing (unless you are thinking strictly in terms of whether the meaning is literal or not. In this case, you could be said to be "giving" the speech to someone).

Comment: @nxx, interesting comment that finally gives a definition of what idiomaticity is ('how other languages/cultures phrase the same thing'), +1.

Comment: Edwin, if I may suggest, I think you should add that comment into the answer.

Comment: If you really want "'definitions' of what idiomaticity is', [this work](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=phQ9Fyx1lPsC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=idioms+in+English+pragmatic&source=bl&ots=V-kzUjhU-v&sig=pRDoSGKrQhs1_Np_7HufX4jxiF8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RQG-UtyoB5DwhQeA1YCIBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=idioms%20in%20English%20pragmatic&f=false) is a mere 87 pages attempting to harmonise different views.

Comment: Edwin, as I said before, your comments are very interesting, thank you.

Comment: I'd say that the primary sense of 'idiomatic' (_in common and accepted use_) and that of 'idiom' (_an expression in some way unpredictable, either grammatically or semantically, from the sum of its parts_) confusingly do not correspond.

Comment: Indeed, my comment does not include a full definition of the word. @Elberich Schneider, I was not sure what you were perceiving the definition to be, so worked something (from Merriam Webster, in this case) into my answer. Are you by any chance German? (I'm judging by your username here). If so, I would love to know the German equivalent of "giving a speech".

Comment: @nxx, sorry, no I'm not German, so I cannot say what that equivalent is; nevertheless I want to thank you for that very nice interest about German language, and, if any, mind that we have a sister site specifically tailored for German Language Learners.

Comment: Thanks! I am living in Germany and very much still a learner. I need to check out that site!

Comment: @nxx, http://german.stackexchange.com, and, among others, I think *Em1* user can give you a hand.

Comment: @nxx I think the German equivalent of "giving a speech" is "eine Rede halten".

Comment: Ah, yes, that does ring a bell. So not the same as the English wording then.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than asking whether "give a speech" is idiomatic, the OP should be asking if "give" can be collocated with *speech*. The answer is yes, give, is often collocated as are the following verbs: *make*, *deliver* and *hold a speech*.

Adjectives which are often collocated with *speech* are:

brief, little, short | interminable, long, long-winded, rambling, major | eloquent, excellent, emotional, impassioned, rousing, stirring,  impromptu, opening, and after-dinner.

Any of the ones suggested above would fit in nicely with the OP's example text.